# How to change the sampling rate for android touch event?

Tags: android, frameworks, touch

I've searched in google and android develop site about the issue that the 
sampling rate of the touch event is too low. However, most of the information 
obtained is in opposite side. Many docs discuss about that the sampling rate is 
too high such that it causes game programming to slow down the frame rate. 
It's said that this is fixed in some android version.

Now I come up with the problem. I desired to develop a handwriting note app 
which requires the touch event handling. I noticed that the touch event triggered (or to said, captured in onTouch function) is not as frequently as I want. It seems only tens of touch events captured in onTouch() and the points are not enough to make a smooth handwriting.

Does anyone knows how to increase the sampling rate of the touch event? I wonder 
whether this is a hardware issue or because of android framework may filter some of the 
event. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks....

BR

Yi-Ju

Comment: I don't think there is any way to increase that

Answer (score 0):

You set the rate when you register a sensor listener. However as the documentation states it is just a hint to the system, the actual rate will most likely be hardware dependent

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener, android.hardware.Sensor, int, android.os.Handler)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int,%20android.os.Handler%29)

Comment: SensorManagers listen for things like acceleration and orientation of the phone, not Touch Events. As far as I know there is no equivalent for onTouchListeners

Comment: I tried to register for all sensors since I can't find touch event sensor and it didn't get better. I just wonder whether this is an android framework issue or hardware driver issue. The touch experience in my acer a500 is much much worse than ipad. Till now, I can't find a way to enhance the experience. Disappointed...

Comment: Ah touch, my bad. I guess there may something you could do by delving into the NDK but thats beyond me.